# python file.truncate Errno 13 permission denied

Tags: python-2.7

I have written a simple python script to delete older revision history from '.h' or '.c' file.

Here is code:

```
import mmap

f = open("D:\MyFile.h", "r+");
m = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0);
index = m.find("/*+- Revision History");

if (index):
    print index;

f.seek(index);
f.truncate();
f.close();
```

It gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python27/Omni", line 15, in <module>
    f.truncate();
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Answer (score 1):

please change the mode to open the file like this

```
f = open("D:/MyFile.h", "r+");
f.truncate()
f.close()
```

since you didnt have write permission on that file, it was getting that error. hope this will resolve the issue. 
Hope you are using windows system. Then follow the above step. It worked for me.My python version is 2.6.
since you want to do truncate that removes all data from the file, it needs write permission, so I used `r+` .

Comment: Already tried that, it says: (python version = 2.7.6)                                   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Omni.py", line 3, in <module>
    f = open("D:\MyFile.h", "rw+");
ValueError: Invalid mode ('rw+')

Comment: I have modified my previous answer, please go through it.

Comment: "ValueError: cannot mmap an empty file": When a file with a 'w' or 'w+' is opened, the existing file with the same name is erased. (From Python Docs).

Comment: yes you are right. anyway, please use frontslash (/). I got desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully ran the same program on ubuntu and it works perfectly fine. I guess there is something to do with windows permission.